# "Graf" or "paragraph"

Tags: nouns

I've often seen the words *graf* and *paragraph* used seemingly interchangeably, but I've never read or heard it explained when each should be used (or if they are indeed interchangeable).

Are they equivalent, or are there circumstances in which one makes more sense than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Graf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nut_graph)* is only used in journalism as a contraction of *(nutshell) paragraph*.

Comment: Some dictionaries, such as Wiktionary, include [graf](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/graf#English), listing it as slang used in journalism. A [2007 Language Log post](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004380.html) also addresses *graf* and other journalism terms with odd spellings (hed, dek, lede, and tk).

Comment: *Graf* also refers to graffiti art style.